# Generate ID and reference in html by XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

please help me. I am facing problem while gererating Id and reference it where its data is matching.

**INPUT:** This is my input snipp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <table>
        <tr><td>para 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>para 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>para 3</td></tr>
    </table>

    <para>para 1</para>
    <para>para 2</para>
    <para>para 3</para>
</root>
```

**XSLT:** which i am using now to transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xhtml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <head>First HTML</head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <xsl:variable name="cur" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <a href="{concat('#',generate-id(para[. = $cur]))}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </a>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:** By transforming i am getting this result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
   <head>First HTML</head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <a href="#">para 1</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <a href="#">para 2</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <a href="#">para 3</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p id="d1e12">para 1</p>
      <p id="d1e14">para 2</p>
      <p id="d1e16">para 3</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:** It should be reference when text of td and p is matching.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
   <head>First HTML</head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <a href="#d1e12">para 1</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <a href="#d1e14">para 2</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <a href="#d1e16">para 3</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p id="d1e12">para 1</p>
      <p id="d1e14">para 2</p>
      <p id="d1e16">para 3</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `para` elements with a path like `//para` e.g. `<a href="{concat('#',generate-id(//para[. = $cur]))}">` which can be simplified to `<a href="#{generate-id(//para[. = $cur])}">`.

It is more efficient to define a key however:  `<xsl:key name="para-content" match="para" use="."/>` and then use `<a href="#{generate-id(key('para-content', .))}">...`